# Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Python pandas DataFrame `rpt`:

```
rpt
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 47518 entries, ('000002', '20120331') to ('603366', '20091231')
Data columns:
STK_ID                    47518  non-null values
STK_Name                  47518  non-null values
RPT_Date                  47518  non-null values
sales                     47518  non-null values
```

I can filter the rows whose stock id is `'600809'` like this: `rpt[rpt['STK_ID'] == '600809']`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 25 entries, ('600809', '20120331') to ('600809', '20060331')
Data columns:
STK_ID                    25  non-null values
STK_Name                  25  non-null values
RPT_Date                  25  non-null values
sales                     25  non-null values
```

and I want to get all the rows of some stocks together, such as `['600809','600141','600329']`. That means I want a syntax like this:

```
stk_list = ['600809','600141','600329']

rst = rpt[rpt['STK_ID'] in stk_list] # this does not works in pandas
```

Since pandas not accept above command, how to achieve the target?

Comment: stk_list = ['600809','600141','600329'] result=filter(lambda item: item in stk_list,df['STK_ID'])  you can use filter to get a list of iterable items.

Answer (score 863, accepted):

Use the `isin` method:

`rpt[rpt['STK_ID'].isin(stk_list)]`

Comment: what about the negation of this- what would be the correct way of going about a `!isin()`?

Comment: @dbyte: You just use the `~` operator: `rpt[~rpt['STK_ID'].isin(stk_list)]`

Comment: Is there a direct way to do this on one level of a multiindex (i.e. without the reset_index?)

Comment: Related to what @mathtick asked: is there a way to do this on an index in general (needn't necessarily be a multindex)?

Comment: @user1669710: Indexes also have an `isin` method.

Comment: In case anyone needs the syntax for an index: `df[df.index.isin(ls)]` where ls is your list

Comment: @stites did you manage to find a not isin?

Comment: @toasteez — yes, I recall the `~` being what I needed.

Comment: Wow, this saved me so much time. I was originally finding my unique values and then iterating over the list and doing a query on the dataframe for EACH unique value. Took over 12 hours with one of my dataframes! I used `isin` and it took 36.5 seconds!

Comment: isin is LIGHTNING quick.  I didn't know it, and was using a lambda function to test "in", and it was sooooooooooo slow.

Comment: How to eliminate possible repeated values?

Comment: what about if you need to check two columns of a dataframe? let's say we want to check if the values of the list isin either 'STK_ID' or 'sales'?

Answer (score 133):

`isin()` is ideal if you have a list of exact matches, but if you have a list of partial matches or substrings to look for, you can filter using the [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.contains.html) method and regular expressions.

For example, if we want to return a DataFrame where all of the stock IDs which begin with `'600'` and then are followed by any three digits:

```
>>> rpt[rpt['STK_ID'].str.contains(r'^600[0-9]{3}$')] # ^ means start of string
...   STK_ID   ...                                    # [0-9]{3} means any three digits
...  '600809'  ...                                    # $ means end of string
...  '600141'  ...
...  '600329'  ...
...      ...   ...
```

Suppose now we have a list of strings which we want the values in `'STK_ID'` to end with, e.g.

```
endstrings = ['01$', '02$', '05$']
```

We can join these strings with the regex 'or' character `|` and pass the string to `str.contains` to filter the DataFrame:

```
>>> rpt[rpt['STK_ID'].str.contains('|'.join(endstrings)]
...   STK_ID   ...
...  '155905'  ...
...  '633101'  ...
...  '210302'  ...
...      ...   ...
```

Finally, `contains` can ignore case (by setting `case=False`), allowing you to be more general when specifying the strings you want to match.

For example,

```
str.contains('pandas', case=False)
```

would match `PANDAS`, `PanDAs`, `paNdAs123`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this.. regex search would be very help. Even, though `isin` only works for perfect matched, it accepts `dataframes`, `Series`, `Index` etc.. @jakevdp provided a great solution here, which works to extract the matching values of `df1`, given another dataframe `df2`:https://stackoverflow.com/a/33282617/4752883. In my case, I have a `df2`, but the values in `df2` wont be exact matches, so I am wondering if there is a way to use `regex` in `isin` (or another function), similar to what you pointed out here?

Answer (score 48):

You can also directly [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) your DataFrame for this information.

```
rpt.query('STK_ID in (600809,600141,600329)')
```

Or similarly search for ranges:

```
rpt.query('60000 < STK_ID < 70000')
```

Comment: or to query by a list named `my_list` `rpt.query('STK_ID in @my_list')`

Answer (score 47):

you can also use ranges by using:

```
b = df[(df['a'] > 1) & (df['a'] < 5)]
```

Answer (score 33):

## Slicing data with pandas

Given a dataframe like this:

```
    RPT_Date  STK_ID STK_Name  sales
0 1980-01-01       0   Arthur      0
1 1980-01-02       1    Beate      4
2 1980-01-03       2    Cecil      2
3 1980-01-04       3     Dana      8
4 1980-01-05       4     Eric      4
5 1980-01-06       5    Fidel      5
6 1980-01-07       6   George      4
7 1980-01-08       7     Hans      7
8 1980-01-09       8   Ingrid      7
9 1980-01-10       9    Jones      4
```

There are multiple ways of selecting or slicing the data.

#### Using .isin

The most obvious is the `.isin` feature. You can create a mask that gives you a series of `True`/`False` statements, which can be applied to a dataframe like this:

```
mask = df['STK_ID'].isin([4, 2, 6])

mask
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: STK_ID, dtype: bool

df[mask]
    RPT_Date  STK_ID STK_Name  sales
2 1980-01-03       2    Cecil      2
4 1980-01-05       4     Eric      4
6 1980-01-07       6   George      4
```

Masking is the ad-hoc solution to the problem, but does not always perform well in terms of speed and memory.

#### With indexing

By setting the index to the `STK_ID` column, we can use the pandas builtin slicing object `.loc`

```
df.set_index('STK_ID', inplace=True)
         RPT_Date STK_Name  sales
STK_ID                           
0      1980-01-01   Arthur      0
1      1980-01-02    Beate      4
2      1980-01-03    Cecil      2
3      1980-01-04     Dana      8
4      1980-01-05     Eric      4
5      1980-01-06    Fidel      5
6      1980-01-07   George      4
7      1980-01-08     Hans      7
8      1980-01-09   Ingrid      7
9      1980-01-10    Jones      4

df.loc[[4, 2, 6]]
         RPT_Date STK_Name  sales
STK_ID                           
4      1980-01-05     Eric      4
2      1980-01-03    Cecil      2
6      1980-01-07   George      4
```

This is the fast way of doing it, even if the indexing can take a little while, it saves time if you want to do multiple queries like this.

#### Merging dataframes

This can also be done by merging dataframes. This would fit more for a scenario where you have a lot more data than in these examples.

```
stkid_df = pd.DataFrame({"STK_ID": [4,2,6]})
df.merge(stkid_df, on='STK_ID')
   STK_ID   RPT_Date STK_Name  sales
0       2 1980-01-03    Cecil      2
1       4 1980-01-05     Eric      4
2       6 1980-01-07   George      4
```

## Note

All the above methods work even if there are multiple rows with the same `'STK_ID'`

Comment: what about if you need to check two columns of a dataframe? let's say we want to check if the values of the list isin either 'STK_ID' or 'sales'?

Answer (score 21):

You can also achieve similar results by using 'query' and @:

eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5]})
list_of_values = [3,6]
result= df.query("A in @list_of_values")
result
   A  B
1  6  2
2  3  3
```

Comment: This syntax is elegant, and this answer deserving of more upvotes

Answer (score 7):

You can use `query`, i.e.:

```
b = df.query('a > 1 & a < 5')
```