# Extracting all rows from pandas Dataframe that have certain value in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am relatively new to Python/Pandas and am struggling with extracting the correct data from a pd.Dataframe. What I actually have is a Dataframe with 3 columns:

```
data =

Position Letter Value
1        a      TRUE
2        f      FALSE
3        c      TRUE
4        d      TRUE
5        k      FALSE
```

What I want to do is put all of the TRUE rows into a new Dataframe so that the answer would be:

```
answer = 

Position Letter Value
1        a      TRUE
3        c      TRUE
4        d      TRUE
```

I know that you can access a particular column using

```
data['Value']
```

but how do I extract all of the TRUE rows?

Thanks for any help and advice,

Alex

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to filter the DataFrame rows of pandas by "within"/"in"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can test which Values are True:

```
In [11]: data['Value'] == True
Out[11]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
```

and then use fancy indexing to pull out those rows:

```
In [12]: data[data['Value'] == True]
Out[12]:
   Position Letter Value
0         1      a  True
2         3      c  True
3         4      d  True
```

*Note: if the values are actually the strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` (they probably shouldn't be!) then use:

```
data['Value'] == 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your value/values in a list and do the following:

```
new_df = df.loc[df['yourColumnName'].isin(['your', 'list', 'items'])]
```

This will return a new dataframe consisting of rows where **your list items** match **your column name** in df.