# Filtering rows from pandas dataframe using concatenated strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe plus a pandas series of identifiers, and would like to filter the rows from the dataframe that correspond to the identifiers in the series. To get the identifiers from the dataframe, I need to concatenate its first two columns. I have tried various things to filter, but none seem to work so far. Here is what I have tried:

1) I tried adding a column of booleans to the data frame, being true if that row corresponds to one of the identifiers, and false otherwise (hoping to be able to do filtering afterwards using the new column):

```
df["isInAcids"] = (df["AcNo"] + df["Sortcode"]) in acids
```

where

```
acids
```

is the series containing the identifiers.

However, this gives me a

```
TypeError: unhashable type
```

2) I tried filtering using the apply function:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x["AcNo"] + x["Sortcode"] in acids, axis = 1)]
```

This doesn't give me an error, but the length of the data frame remains unchanged, so it doesn't appear to filter anything.

3) I have added a new column, containing the concatenated strings/identifiers, and then try to filter afterwards (see [Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in)):

```
df["ACIDS"] = df["AcNo"] + df["Sortcode"]
df[df["ACIDS"].isin(acids)]
```

But again, the dataframe doesn't change.

I hope this makes sense...

Any suggestions where I might be going wrong?
Thanks,
Anne

Comment: Could you post a small sample of what your `dataframe` and `series` and what you expect your results to look like?

Comment: These operations are not inplace, so the dataframe won't just change unless you explicitly tell it to (this is a **good** thing).

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks a lot, if I add `df = ...` in the third solution it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking for something like the following:

```
In [1]: other_ids = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'])

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
  ids  vals
0   a     1
1   b     2
2   c     3
3   f     4

In [4]: other_ids
Out[4]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    c
dtype: object
```

In this case, the series `other_ids` would be like your series `acids`.  We want to select just those rows of `df` whose `id` is in the series `other_ids`.  To do that we'll use the `dataframe`'s method `.isin()`.

```
In [5]: df.ids.isin(other_ids)
Out[5]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: ids, dtype: bool
```

This gives a column of bools that we can index into:

```
In [6]: df[df.ids.isin(other_ids)]
Out[6]: 
  ids  vals
0   a     1
1   b     2
2   c     3
```

This is close to what you're doing with your 3rd attempt.  Once you post a sample of your dataframe I can edit this answer, if it doesn't work already.

Reading a bit more, you may be having trouble because you have two columns in `df` that are your ids?  `Dataframe` doesn't have an `isin` method, but we can get around that with something like:

```
In [26]: df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'f'], 
'ids2': ['e', 'f', 'c', 'f']})

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
  ids ids2  vals
0   a    e     1
1   b    f     2
2   f    c     3
3   f    f     4

In [28]: df.ids.isin(ids) + df.ids2.isin(ids)
Out[28]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

`True` is like 1 and `False` is like zero so we add the two boolean series from the two `isins()` to get something like an `OR` operation.  Then like before we can index into this boolean series:

```
In [29]: new = df.ix[df.ids.isin(ids) + df.ids2.isin(ids)]

In [30]: new
Out[30]: 
  ids ids2  vals
0   a    e     1
1   b    f     2
2   f    c     3
```

Comment: I think the main confusion from this question is that these operations are not inplace (ie you need to set `df = df[df.ids.isin(other_ids)]`)

Comment: I think that's right.  The other issue *might* be that she has two columns for `ids`, where I have one.  Is there a reason that `dataframe` doesn't have an `isin()` method with some options like `or` and `and`?

Comment: Nah that should be ok. I think it's more efficient to do the or/and afterwards, so pandas takes an executive decision that you should do that.

Comment: I'll open a GH issue.  No promise on a PR though.  I really need to get back to work :)

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks a lot for the example. I have extended it to what I need: Try `new_ids = pd.Series(["a1,c3"])` and `df = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'ids': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f'], 'stuff':["insert", "whatever","you","fancy"]})`. I would like to filter the rows by appending the string in columns "ids" and "vals" to match what is in new_ids... Preferably without creating an additional column first, as I am doing currently.

Comment: I see what you mean by append now.  Sounds like Andy's comment got it working for you.

Comment: Yes it did. However, if anyone has a better way of doing this (without creating an extra column in which I append the strings) then please do let me know please.

Comment: Doing `df = df[(df["AcNo"] + df["Sortcode"]).isin(acids)]` should work but that's getting a tad unreadable. It still creates the series but it doesn't store it anywhere.