# How to remove rows from a dataframe based on their column values existence in another df?

Tags: pandas

Given two dataframes A and B, which both have columns 'x', 'y' how can I *efficiently* remove all rows in A that their pairs of (x, y) appear in B.

I thought about implementing it using a row iterator on A and then per pair checking if it exists in B but I am guessing this is the least efficient way...

I tried using the .isin function as suggested in [Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in) but couldn't make use of it for multiple columns.

Example dataframes:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [3, 4], [2, 4]], columns=['x', 'y'])
B = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['x', 'y'])
```

C should contain [1,4] and [2,4] after the operation.

Comment: Are there possible duplicate rows in A itseld? And what to do with them?

Comment: The isin method will work with DataFrames in .13

Comment: @TomAugspurger I don't think it will work for this case, as it needs to have the same rows, so combination of two values, not just the same value as in a column + it does not need to match on the index.

Comment: @joris, there are no duplicate rows in A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas master (or in future 0.13) `isin` will also accept DataFrames, but the problem is that it just looks at the values in each column, and not at an exact row combination of the columns.

Taken from @AndyHayden comment here (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4421#issuecomment-23052472), a similar approach with set:

```
In [3]: mask = pd.Series(map(set(B.itertuples(index=False)).__contains__, A.itertuples(index=False)))
In [4]: A[~mask]
Out[4]:
   x  y
1  1  4
3  2  4
```

Or a more readable version:

```
set_B = set(B.itertuples(index=False))
mask = [x not in set_B for x in A.itertuples(index=False)]
```

The possible advantage of this compared to @Acorbe's answer is that this preserves the index of `A` and does not remove duplicate rows in `A` (but that depends on what you want of course).

---

As I said, 0.13 will have accept DataFrames to `isin`. However, I don't think this will solve this issue because also the index has to be the same:

```
In [27]: A.isin(B)
Out[27]:
       x      y
0   True   True
1  False   True
2  False  False
3  False  False
```

You can solve this by converting it to a dict, but now it does not look at the combinatio of both columns, but just for each column seperately:

```
In [28]: A.isin(B.to_dict(outtype='list'))
Out[28]:
       x     y
0   True  True
1   True  True
2   True  True
3  False  True
```

Comment: Preserving the index is indeed an important detail I haven't taken into account and do need. In the more readable version a conversion of the mask to a pandas series is missing. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! In the first version, I converted to a Series because I needed the boolean inverted (with `~`), and this is not possible with a list. But in the more readable version, this inversion is already included in the list comprehension (`not in`). But indeed, then just `A[mask]` is needed without `~`.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a single-column solution:

```
new_df = df1[~df1["column_name"].isin(df2["column_name"])]
```

The ~ is a logical operator for NOT.

So this will create a new dataframe when the values of df1["column_name"] are not found in df2["column_name"]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to generate two `sets`, say `A_set`, `B_set`, whose elements are the rows of the `DataFrames`. Hence, the fast set difference operation `A_set - B_set` can be used.

```
 A_set = set(map(tuple,A.values))   #we need to have an hashable object before generating a set
 B_set = set(map(tuple,B.values))  

 C_set = A_set - B_set 
 C_set
    {(1, 4), (2, 4)}

 C = pd.DataFrame([c for c in C_set], columns=['x','y'])  

        x  y
     0  2  4
     1  1  4
```

This procedure involves some preliminary conversion operations, though.