# Extract: Python dictionary, key with multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two files and I am trying to extract some values from file 1, like this:

```
File1:
2    word1
4    word2
4    word2_1
4    word2_2
8    word5
8    word5_3

File 2:
4
8
```

What I want is to extract every lines starting by 4 and 8 (from file 2) and they are lots.
So usually if only one line would match I would use a python dictionary, one key one element easy! But now that I have multiple element matching to the same key, my script would only extract the last one (obviously as it goes along it will erase previous ones!).
So I get this is not how it works but I have no idea and I would be very happy if someone can help me start.

Here is my "usual" code:

```
gene_count = {}
my_file = open('file1.txt')
for line in my_file:
    columns = line.strip().split()
    gene = columns[0]
    count = columns[1:13]
    gene_count[gene] = count

names_file = open('file2.txt')
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in names_file:
    gene = line.strip()
    count = gene_count[gene]
    output_file.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(gene,"\t".join(count)))

output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the values of your dictionary, lists, and append to them.

In general:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [])

for x in xrange(101):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        my_dict['evens'].append(str(x))
    else:
        my_dict['odds'].append(str(x))

print 'evens:', ' '.join(my_dict['evens'])
print 'odds:', ' '.join(my_dict['odds'])
```

In your case, your values are lists, so add (concatenate) the lists to the lists of your dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
gene_count = defaultdict(lambda: [])

my_file = open('file1.txt')
for line in my_file:
    columns = line.strip().split()
    gene = columns[0]
    count = columns[1:13]
    gene_count[gene] += count

names_file = open('file2.txt')
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')

for line in names_file:
    gene = line.strip()
    count = gene_count[gene]
    output_file.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(gene,"\t".join(count)))

output_file.close()
```

If what you actually want to print is the count for each gene, then replace `"\t".join(count)` with `len(count)`, the length of the list.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now! Make a list !!! Okay just one more tiny question, is there a way to get the results in a "nicer" output? right now with your code I get 4 [[word1],[word2]] … would it be possible to get them more like `4 word1 \n 4 word2`? Otherwise I can always use sed or awk afterwards but I was just wondering! Thanks!!

Comment: I updated it to address that issue, that's what `"\t".join(count)` should do.

Comment: I add to remove it: Error : output_file.write('{0}\t{1}\n'.format(gene,"\t".join(count)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: Is `gene` still `line.strip()` in your program? Because the error refers to `gene`

Comment: The problem was `gene_count[gene].append(count)` was appending a list to a list. Here `count` was a list, `count = columns[1:13]`. So use the `+` operator instead. See my edit.

Comment: I am still working on the output, its a bit weird but I will figure it out now that I understand the concept, thanks a lot for your help really appreciate it!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60507/discussion-between-user3188922-and-oregontrail).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/). You can load files into `DataFrame` and then filter them:

```
In [5]: file1 = pn.read_csv('file1',sep='    ', 
                            names=['number','word'],
                            engine='python')

In [6]: file1
Out[6]: 
   number     word
0       2    word1
1       4    word2
2       4  word2_1
3       4  word2_2
4       8    word5
5       8  word5_3

In [9]: file1[(file1.number==4) | (file1.number==8)]
Out[9]: 
   number     word
1       4    word2
2       4  word2_1
3       4  word2_2
4       8    word5
5       8  word5_3

In [13]: foo = file1[(file1.number==4) | (file1.number==8)].append(file2[(file2.number==4) | (file2.number==8)])
Out[13]: 
   number     word
1       4    word2
2       4  word2_1
3       4  word2_2
4       8    word5
5       8  word5_3
1       4    word2
2       4  word2_1
3       4  word2_2
4       8    word5
5       8  word5_3
```

In 5 you reed file, in 9 you filter file by values of numbers, in 13 you join two filtered files together.
You can then sort it and do your computation much easier then with dictionary.

**UPDATE**
To filter `pandas.DataFrame` by condition that column value is in some list you can use [`isin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in) giving it list or using `range` for example.

```
In [46]: file1[file1.number.isin([1,2,3])]
Out[46]: 
   number   word
0       2  word1
```

Comment: It's interesting, never heard about pandas I will check it out! But what if file 2 is 1000 lines, you can't just do it manually!`?!

Comment: I don't quite get what you meany by "do it manually", please explain.

Comment: I just meant you seem to enter one line of code with for example (file1.number==4), but what if the number 4 may take up to 1000 different number? Anyway I don't know anything at all about pandas but I will check it out, thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can use `isin` like this: `In [46]: file1[file1.number.isin([1,2,3])]`