# Filter Column in Pandas Pivot - Python

Tags: python, filter, pandas, pivot, dataframe

My data frame and pivot table look like this:

```
df = DataFrame(x, columns=y)
table = pivot_table(df, index='NandAID',columns='StockID',values='LineNET',aggfunc=np.sum)
```

StockID is a list of 2000 different items, and I only want to see for example 'stockitem1', 'stockitem2' ...

How can I do this?

I have tired stuff along the lines of table.ix('...') but I am not sure what I am doing.

Comment: Regarding the list of items that you want to filter on: 1. Is the list small or large? 2. Is there a specific pattern that the list items (strings) follow?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in/12065904#12065904

Comment: Thanks @TomAugspurger!!! Couldn't find that question anywhere and I knew it must have been asked!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's easier to search for things when you already know what the answer is.