# Pandas DataFrame index by belonging to a set

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that, among the columns, has one called Phone_Number. I want to get just the rows that have a phone number that shows 50 times or more. My best attempt was this:

```
counts = data.Phone_Number.value_counts()
counts = counts[counts.values > 50]
data[data.Phone_Number in counts.index]
```

I get, however, this error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

What would be the best way to get the rows in the data frame for this situation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `isin()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in/26724725

Comment: Thank you, @ajcr! It does not throw an error, but I get an empty set, which I thought wasn't possible (the counts set is not empty, and was generated from the phone numbers contained in 'data')

Comment: That's odd, I would have thought `data[data.Phone_Number.isin(counts.index)]` would work. Are you able to post a small sample of your data?

Comment: @ajcr thanks again, my mistake was not to use isin(counts.index) but just isin(counts), this is also a valid solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with `filter`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some artificial data
# ===================================================
np.random.seed(0)
# 450 rows/records in total
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, 450), columns=['Phone_Number'])

Out[74]: 
 Phone_Number
0               6
1               1
2               4
3               4
4               8
5               4
6               6
7               3
..            ...
442             7
443             1
444             9
445             1
446             8
447             7
448             6
449             7

[450 rows x 1 columns]

# processing
# ===================================================

# filtered results: 177 rows
df.groupby('Phone_Number').filter(lambda group: group.count() > 50)

Out[75]: 
     Phone_Number
2               4
3               4
5               4
8               5
11              9
12              9
17              9
20              9
..            ...
424             5
426             4
428             5
430             5
431             5
436             4
441             4
444             9

[177 rows x 1 columns]

# for reference: 71+54+52 = 177
df.Phone_Number.value_counts()

Out[76]: 
4    71
9    54
5    52
1    50
8    49
3    45
6    44
2    43
7    42
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

The method above works to solve your problem instance. In general though, if you want to index a pandas dataframe by belonging to a set, you can use isin like so:

```
counts = data.Phone_Number.value_counts()
counts = counts[counts.values > 50]
data[data.Phone_Number.isin(counts.index)]
```