# How do I use within / in operator in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select data from my CSV file.

Though I can get a data in which column

```
"House" == 1 (any single number)
```

as following, I don't know how to get the data where

```
"House" in [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 30, 34, 46, 57, 58, 61, 86, 89, 102, 121, 156].
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('../../data/training_dataset_500.csv')
df[df['House']==1]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried df[df['House']==[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 30, 34, 46, 57, 58, 61, 86, 89, 102, 121, 156]]

Comment: I also tried df[df['House']==1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 30, 34, 46, 57, 58, 61, 86, 89, 102, 121, 156]

Comment: Sorry i am a beginner..

Comment: The problem is that you ask a ton of questions since yesterday without first searching for the answer.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to filter the dataframe rows of pandas by "within"/"in"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: yeah.. true... I am also searching but I cannot find it..I will try to search infomation by myself. sorry..

Comment: Try googling "pandas filter column value list" or using the SO search box.

Also you should post specific titles to the problem you're having

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, there are already two duplicates out there

Comment: Sorry I will close it. thank you Anand

Comment: The referenced questions are not answers to this question. This question asks how to use the in operator. In pandas in and is_in are NOT the same.

Comment: Its annoying when people vote close before understanding the question. 
There *is* a correct answer to this question (which is not the one marked correct). Now I can't provide it.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the [`Series.isin()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method to check if a series value is in a list of values. In your case -

```
df[df['House'].isin([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 28, 30, 34, 46, 57, 58, 61, 86, 89, 102, 121, 156])]
```

Example -

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8

In [78]: df[df['A'].isin([1,2])]
Out[78]:
   A  B
0  1  5
1  2  6
```