# How to filter in python?

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeRhb.png)
I am trying to do a filter within a column on a csv file. For the county_name column I want only the texas states. Similarly to how in excel I would filter to have the counties containing tx for that column. Any help on how to do so?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JS0U.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO please read how to post question guidelines or else your question will be downvoted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Remove all the images and make them like tables using markdown syntax.

Comment: Presumably you are using Pandas so try searching existing pandas questions on how to select rows based on column values.  Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595146/how-do-i-use-within-in-operator-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335207/14973743

Comment: Update: You might also want `table.county_name.str.contains('tx')` or something like that.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran suggestion is actually btter for a duplicate

Comment: Lots of ways to go on this problem. If you don't want to install any new modules, then you can look at the built-in [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). If you find yourself using tabular data a lot, it might pay to learn to use the [Pandas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. Finally, there are a number of modules that can be used to manipulate Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df =df.loc[df['county_name'].str.split(",")[1] == 'tx']
```

You can filter county_name col for tx and store it in a new_df like excel