# filter by array numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to filter my ndarray by another array I have collected (with the same values)

My main ndarray looks like

```
[['Name' 'Col1' 'Count']
 ['test' '' '413']
 ['erd' ' ' '60']
 ..., 
 ['Td1' 'f' '904']
 ['Td2' 'K' '953']
 ['Td3' 'r' '111']]
```

I have another list with various matching names

```
names = ['Td1','test','erd']
```

**What I'd Like to Do**

I'd like to use the list names as a filter against the ndarray above?

**What I've Tried**

```
name_filter = main_ndarray[:,0] == names
```

This does not work

**What I'd Expect**

```
[['Name' 'Col1' 'Count']
 ['test' '' '413']
 ['erd' ' ' '60']
 ['Td1' 'f' '904']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using Pandas for this kind of data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Name', 'Col1', 'Count'],
        ['test', '', '413'],
        ['erd', ' ', '60'],
        ['Td1', 'f', '904'],
        ['Td2', 'K', '953'],
        ['Td3', 'r', '111']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
names = ['Td1','test','erd']
result = df[df.Name.isin(names)]
```

Results:

```
>>> df
   Name Col1 Count
0  test        413
1   erd         60
2   Td1    f   904
3   Td2    K   953
4   Td3    r   111
>>> result
   Name Col1 Count
0  test        413
1   erd         60
2   Td1    f   904
>>>
```

References

- http://pandas.pydata.org/
- [Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12065885/553404)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` function too.

```
cats_array = numpy.array(
 [['Name' ,'Col1', 'Count'],
 ['test', '' ,'413'],
 ['erd' ,' ' ,'60'],
 ['Td1' ,'f' ,'904'],
 ['Td2' ,'K' ,'953'],
 ['Td3' ,'r', '111']]
 )

 names = ['Td1','test','erd']

 filter(lambda x: x[0] in names, cats_array)
```

gives:

```
[array(['test', '', '413'],
       dtype='|S5'), array(['erd', ' ', '60'],
       dtype='|S5'), array(['Td1', 'f', '904'],
       dtype='|S5')]
```

Comment: So out of curiosity what would I do with that array now? it didn't retain the "regular" formatting. It now has this dtype in there and the values in index 1 are completely separate from a contiguous array

Comment: @cat You can hit it with `map(lambda a: list(a), filter(lambda x: x[0] in names, cats_array))` to keep a list-like formatting. If you do that, your answer will be `[['test', '', '413'], ['erd', ' ', '60'], ['Td1', 'f', '904']]`

Answer (score 1):

I would also go with @YXD's Pandas solution but just for the sake of completeness I also provide a simple solution based on list comprehension:

```
data = [['Name', 'Col1', 'Count'],
 ['test', '', '413'],
 ['erd', ' ', '60'],
 ['Td1', 'f', '904'],
 ['Td2', 'K', '953'],
 ['Td3', 'r', '111']]

names = ['Td1', 'test', 'erd']

# select all sublist of data
res = [l for l in data if l[0] in names]

# insert the first row of data
res.insert(0, data[0])
```

which then gives you the desired output:

```
[['Name', 'Col1', 'Count'],
 ['test', '', '413'],
 ['erd', ' ', '60'],
 ['Td1', 'f', '904']]
```