# How to remove all rows from one dataframe that are part of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like this

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': list('abcaewar'),
        'B': list('ghjglmgb'),
        'C': list('lkjlytle'),
        'ignore': ['stuff'] * 8
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': list('abfu'),
        'B': list('ghio'),
        'C': list('lkqw'),
        'stuff': ['ignore'] * 4
    }
)
```

and I would like to remove all rows in `df1` where `A`, `B` and `C` are identical to values in `df2`, so in the above case the expected outcome is

```
   A  B  C ignore
0  c  j  j  stuff
1  e  l  y  stuff
2  w  m  t  stuff
3  r  b  e  stuff
```

One way of achieving this would be

```
comp_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df1 = df1.set_index(comp_columns)
df2 = df2.set_index(comp_columns)

keep_ind = [
    ind for ind in df1.index if ind not in df2.index
]

new_df1 = df1.loc[keep_ind].reset_index()
```

Does anyone see a more straightforward way of doing this which avoids the `reset_index()` operations and the loop to identify non-overlapping indices, e.g. by a mart way of masking? Ideally, I don't have to hardcode the columns, but can define them in a list as above as I sometimes need 2, sometimes 3 or sometimes 4 or more columns for the removal.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044498/9081267)

Comment: @Erfan: Thanks. I could guess that that is already out there, but missed it while googling...

Comment: Well, it;s not always easy to find these specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with optional parameter `indicator=True`, then use boolean masking to filter the rows in `df1`:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2[['A', 'B', 'C']], on=['A', 'B', 'C'], indicator=True, how='left')
df3 = df3[df3.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
```

Result:

```
# print(df3)

   A  B  C ignore
2  c  j  j  stuff
4  e  l  y  stuff
5  w  m  t  stuff
7  r  b  e  stuff
```

Comment: Quite elegant, thanks (upvoted); did not know about `indicator`, that is quite a handy one...