# Detecting differences in a Pandas Dataframe - use of lambdas in .loc[] syntax

Tags: python, pandas

I am referring to this article:

https://kanoki.org/2019/07/04/pandas-difference-between-two-dataframes/

I don't understand this particular syntax for loc, where a lambda is doing the row filtering?

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']
```

What is this lambda doing, I know the end result - just trying to understand the use of lambdas in "loc" syntax.

Comment: It would make more sense to do it [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61044498/9081267) way and it's also more readable because of `query`, I don't like the use of `lambda` for filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`loc` accepts (among other things) a one-argument callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) that is called on each row. The callable is expected to return something that can be used as an index (in this case, a boolean).

Effectively, this syntax means "for each row `x` in the merged dataframes, call the lambda on the row and select it if `x['_merge'] == 'left_only'`".

Comment: Is there possible to filter result of merge without lambda, and with chaining methods as in example?

Comment: Yes. As @Erfan pointed out in the comment to the question, you can use `.query('_merge == "left_only"')` to obtain the same result.