# How should I filter one dataframe by entries from another one in pandas with isin?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes (df1, df2). The columns names and indices are the same (the difference in columns entries). Also, df2 has only 20 entries (which also existed in df1 as i said).
I want to filter df1 by df2 entries, but when i try to do it with isin but nothing happens.

```
df1.isin(df2) or df1.index.isin(df2.index)
```

Tell me please what I'm doing wrong and how should I do it..

Comment: I am sure you can find your answer by searching for this. How about ```df1.loc[df2.index]``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select the entries in df1 with an index that is also present in df2, you should be able to do it with:

```
df1.loc[df2.index]
```

or if you really want to use isin:

```
df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

Comment: Such a easy way, and i even didn't try to do that.. Thank you kindly..

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `isin` function in `pandas` returns a Dataframe of `booleans` and not the result you want. So it makes sense that the `cmds` you used did not work.

I am possitive that hte following psot will help

[pandas - filter dataframe by another dataframe by row elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282119/pandas-filter-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-by-row-elements/33282617)