# Pandas multiconditional drop using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I drop some values from a dataframe using another dataframe as parameter?

```
df1
code | reply
A1   | yes
A2   | yes
A3   | no
```

```
df2
code |
A1   |
A1   |
A3   |
```

`df_new = df1.drop(df1['code'] == df2['code'] & df1['reply'] != 'yes')`

```
df_new
code | reply
A1   | yes
```

Is there a simple way to do this using .drop()?

Comment: There are several ways, have a look at those answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282119/pandas-filter-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-by-row-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df1[df1['code'].isin(df2['code']) & df1['reply'].eq('yes')]
```

Output:

```
  code reply
0   A1   yes
```

Comment: Is there a "inverse" of ```.eq()``` in pandas? I'll use it too

Comment: `ne()` is the opposite of `eq()`

Comment: @null92. For your information `AND` and `&` are not the same thing.

Comment: @mozway. In fact, I will removed my answer. It does not make sense to use `merge` here

Answer (score 1):

The logic is unclear but you can accomplish what you want without the use of `drop`:

```
>>> df1[df1['reply'] == 'yes'].merge(df2.drop_duplicates('code'))

  code reply
0   A1   yes
```

Comment: actually your drop and my indexing are equivalent using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), so yes I always try to keep the most simple variant in such cases ;)

Comment: That's why I'm pointing it out to the OP.

Comment: I was about to add this variant and the wikipedia link in my answer so I commented instead as you had just edited ;)

Comment: OK. I removed this part from my answer.