# polars - filter DataFrame by another DataFrame by row elements

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I want to solve the problem described for pandas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282119/pandas-filter-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-by-row-elements/33282617#33282617) in polars.

Especially, consider a DataFrame `df1` that looks like:

```
c  k  l
A  1  a
A  2  b
B  2  a
C  2  a
C  2  d
```

and another DataFrame called `df2` like:

```
c  l
A  b
C  a
```

At outlined in the question above, I would like to filter `df1` for all rows that **are not** in `df2`.

Especially, the expected results looks like this:

```
c  k  l
A  1  a
B  2  a
C  2  d
```

The most-upvoted answer to the questions linked above uses a multiindex constructed from the desired columns. I don't see, how this would work in polars.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like an [anti-join](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/user-guide/transformations/joins/) solves this problem:

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({'c': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                    'k': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    'l': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd']})
df2 = pl.DataFrame({'c': ['A', 'C'],
                    'l': ['b', 'a']})

df1.join(df2, on=["c", "l"], how="anti")
```

[image]