# How to filter one dataframe with a column from another dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with only an 'ID' column in common, and neither column contains unique values. I have read [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282119/pandas-filter-dataframe-by-another-dataframe-by-row-elements) but it doesn't quite achieve my objective.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'g'], 
                     'Price': [7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'e'],
 'Count': [1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2]})
```

I would like to clean df2 by maintaining only the rows where the ID appears in df as well. Ideal outcome:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'e'],
             'Count': [1, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2]})
    ID  Count
0   a   1
1   b   0
2   e   0
3   g   3
4   a   3
5   a   3
6   a   5
7   g   1
8   b   3
9   b   2
10  b   0
11  b   1
12  e   2
```

Please do note that this is just a simple recreation of the problem, df2 in the real thing contains 400k or so rows, so the ideal solution should be scalable.
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: `df2[df2['ID'].isin(df['ID'])]`

Comment: you can use this code to filter df2 based on IDs present in df   
`df2_cleaned = df2[df2['ID'].isin(df['ID'])]`