# Filter DataFrame rows that are lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Data structure:

- A pandas DataFrame (`business_df`) with a column (`category`) of lists that I am interested in
- A list containing restaurant categories (`restaurant_categories_list`)

What I am trying to do:

Filter businesses in the `business_df` based on their `category` column (which has a list structure) by categorizing a business as a restaurant if at least one of its listed categories matches at least one of the restaurant categories.

I checked these 2 questions but they did not provide an answer for my problem:

[Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in)

[use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

I am running this code now:

```
restaurant_categories_list = ['Soup','Sandwiches','Salad', 'Restaurants','Burgers', 'Breakfast & Brunch']
 print(business_df.loc[business_df['categories'].isin(restaurant_categories_list)])
```

And here is the column I am interested in:

```
0                          ['Fast Food', 'Restaurants']
1                                         ['Nightlife']
2                         ['Auto Repair', 'Automotive']
3                  ['Active Life', 'Mini Golf', 'Golf']
4     ['Shopping', 'Home Services', 'Internet Servic...
5     ['Bars', 'American (New)', 'Nightlife', 'Loung...
6     ['Active Life', 'Trainers', 'Fitness & Instruc...
7     ['Bars', 'American (Traditional)', 'Nightlife'...
8                ['Auto Repair', 'Automotive', 'Tires']
9                          ['Active Life', 'Mini Golf']
10                     ['Home Services', 'Contractors']
11                            ['Veterinarians', 'Pets']
12        ['Libraries', 'Public Services & Government']
13              ['Automotive', 'Auto Parts & Supplies']
14    ['Burgers', 'Breakfast & Brunch', 'American (T...
```

So if I am only working with these rows, my expected dataframe should only contain rows 0 and 14.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data?

Comment: adding to @ChuckLoganLim's comment: and expected output please ...

Comment: putting things like lists into dataframes don't seem to give good performance anyways (not really it's intended use case) - you can use `to_dict` to get a python dictionary and iterate over that, or split the lists into columns with true/false per value, which seems more pandas-friendly (not an expert, but have been doing similar stuff last week...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

This version uses `ast.literal_eval()` in order to deserialize lists from strings and it seems to be working properly:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

restaurant_categories_list=['Soup','Sandwiches','Salad', 'Restaurants','Burgers', 'Breakfast & Brunch']

df_orig = pd.read_csv('yelp_academic_dataset_business.csv', low_memory=False)

df = df_orig[(pd.notnull(df_orig['categories']))]

mask = df['categories'].apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series).isin(restaurant_categories_list).sum(axis=1) > 0

print(df.ix[mask, ['categories']])
df[mask].to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
```

But as @CorleyBrigman already said it's very difficult and very inefficient to work with such a data structures using Pandas...

**OLD ANSWER BASED ON SAMPLE DATA:**

you can convert lists to columns/Series then use `pd.isin()` function which will produce a matrix of True/False values, which can be summed up (because in Python: False==0 and True==1):

```
mask = df['business'].apply(pd.Series).isin(restaurant_categories_list).sum(axis=1) > 0
print(df[(mask)])
```

Explanation:

```
print(df['business'].apply(pd.Series))

                0                             1                  2      3
0       Fast Food                   Restaurants                NaN    NaN
1       Nightlife                           NaN                NaN    NaN
2     Auto Repair                    Automotive                NaN    NaN
3     Active Life                     Mini Golf               Golf    NaN
4        Shopping                 Home Services    Internet Servic    NaN
5            Bars                American (New)          Nightlife  Loung
6     Active Life                      Trainers  Fitness & Instruc    NaN
7            Bars        American (Traditional)          Nightlife    NaN
8     Auto Repair                    Automotive              Tires    NaN
9     Active Life                     Mini Golf                NaN    NaN
10  Home Services                   Contractors                NaN    NaN
11  Veterinarians                          Pets                NaN    NaN
12      Libraries  Public Services & Government                NaN    NaN
13     Automotive         Auto Parts & Supplies                NaN    NaN
14        Burgers            Breakfast & Brunch           American    NaN
```

then

```
print(df['business'].apply(pd.Series).isin(restaurant_categories_list))
```

output:

```
        0      1      2      3
0   False   True  False  False
1   False  False  False  False
2   False  False  False  False
3   False  False  False  False
4   False  False  False  False
5   False  False  False  False
6   False  False  False  False
7   False  False  False  False
8   False  False  False  False
9   False  False  False  False
10  False  False  False  False
11  False  False  False  False
12  False  False  False  False
13  False  False  False  False
14   True   True  False  False
```

then

```
mask = df['business'].apply(pd.Series).isin(restaurant_categories_list).sum(axis=1) > 0
print(mask)
```

output:

```
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14     True
dtype: bool
```

and finally:

```
print(df[(mask)])
```

Output:

```
                                   business
0                  [Fast Food, Restaurants]
14  [Burgers, Breakfast & Brunch, American]
```

Comment: it doesn't work (shows zero rows), this one however outputs the first row, but that's not what I want
`df1=business_df.ix[(business_df['categories'].apply(pd.Series).isin(restaurant_categories_list).sum())]
print(df1['categories'])`

Comment: make a pickle of your DF and upload it somewhere so i could test it

Comment: you forgot ` > 0` after the sum - it does matter

Comment: @severine, it works absolutely fine for me: `df[(mask)]` and `df.ix[mask]` - both are working properly

Comment: I am running these lines: `business_df=pd.read_csv('yelp_academic_dataset_business.csv')
restaurant_categories_list=['Soup','Sandwiches','Salad', 'Restaurants','Burgers', 'Breakfast & Brunch']
print(business_df['categories'].apply(pd.Series))` the last line doesn't work for me, it give me the same result as shown above

Comment: link to the csv file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzm2STAcXRzkNk1Gc0ZhbTdWSFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @severine, what column contains categories?

Comment: the column 'categories'

Comment: @severine, check my updated version - it should work properly