# Selecting rows in a DataFrame that are not in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

So I have a DataFrame called `trips` containing the following information:

```
route_id     service_id  shape_id                      trip_id
0     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120805  GH_B6-Weekday-004000_BX12_1
1     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120809  GH_B6-Weekday-009000_BX12_1
2     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120792  GH_B6-Weekday-013000_BX12_1
3     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120809  GH_B6-Weekday-017000_BX12_1
4     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120792  GH_B6-Weekday-021000_BX12_1
...
```

I also have a Series called `invalidTrips` containing the following information:

```
trip_id
11760139-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10         16
11760139-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10-SDon    16
11760140-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10         19
11760140-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10-SDon    19
11760141-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10         16
...
```

How would I select all the rows in `trips` that do not have a `trip_id` matching a `trip_id` in `invalid_trips`?

EDIT: So now I have this code:

```
# Grab the number of trips made outside min and max hour.
tooEarly = stopTimes['arrival_time'] < base_mintime
tooLate = stopTimes['departure_time'] > base_maxtime
invalidTrips = stopTimes[(tooEarly | tooLate)].groupby('trip_id').size()

# Filter out the invalid trips.
print(invalidTrips.size)
print(trips.size)
in_validTrips = ~trips.trip_id.isin(invalidTrips)
validTrips = trips[in_validTrips][['route_id', 'service_id', 'shape_id']]
print(validTrips.size)
```

For whatever reason, even though `invalidTrips.size` can change depending on `base_mintime` and `base_maxtime`, `validTrips.size` remains constant, even though I would expect it to be inversely dependent on `invalidTrips.size`. Why would this be the case?

(For further background information, this is all being pulled from GTFS data.)

Comment: This is closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in basically you can do `trips[~trips['trip_id'].isin(invalid_trips)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

try `isin()` function and `~` operator

as per @EdChum's correction in the comment - if `invalid_trips` is of Series type:

```
trips[~trips.trip_id.isin(invalidTrips.index)]
```

**TEST:**

```
In [39]: invalidTrips
Out[39]:
trip_id
11760139-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10         16
11760139-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10-SDon    16
11760140-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10         19
11760140-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10-SDon    19
11760141-BPPB6-BP_B6-Weekday-10         16
GH_B6-Weekday-017000_BX12_1             11         # <-- i've added it intentionally
Name: val, dtype: int64

In [40]: trips
Out[40]:
  route_id     service_id  shape_id                      trip_id
0     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120805  GH_B6-Weekday-004000_BX12_1
1     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120809  GH_B6-Weekday-009000_BX12_1
2     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120792  GH_B6-Weekday-013000_BX12_1
3     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120809  GH_B6-Weekday-017000_BX12_1  # <-- exclude this row 
4     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120792  GH_B6-Weekday-021000_BX12_1

In [41]: trips[~trips.trip_id.isin(invalidTrips.index)]
Out[41]:
  route_id     service_id  shape_id                      trip_id
0     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120805  GH_B6-Weekday-004000_BX12_1
1     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120809  GH_B6-Weekday-009000_BX12_1
2     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120792  GH_B6-Weekday-013000_BX12_1
4     BX12  GH_B6-Weekday  BX120792  GH_B6-Weekday-021000_BX12_1
```

Comment: I get the error message: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'trip_id'`

Comment: @EdChum, sure,  thank you - i've corrected the answer

Comment: regarding the error, Series have no columns so `trips[~trips.trip_id.isin(invalid_trips)]` should work

Comment: It appears to do something, but not exactly what I want it to do: I edited the original question to add details about what is now happening.