# How to select rows from a python DataFrame by using isin?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to use `isin` to choose rows that the value of `column A` is in `column B`.

For example: I have `my_df`, and I want to select row 0 and 2, because `[aa, ab]` and `[bc, bd]` both in `A` and `B` respectively.

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['aa','ab'],['aa','ac'],['bc','bd']],
                     'B':[[['aa','ab'],['ba','bb'],['bc','bd']],[['aa','ab'],['ba','bb']],[['aa','ab'],['bc','bd']]]})
my_df

    A           B
0   [aa, ab]    [[aa, ab], [ba, bb], [bc, bd]]
1   [aa, ac]    [[aa, ab], [ba, bb]]
2   [bc, bd]    [[aa, ab], [bc, bd]]
```

I want this:

```
    A           B
0   [aa, ab]    [[aa, ab], [ba, bb], [bc, bd]]
2   [bc, bd]    [[aa, ab], [bc, bd]]
```

Comment: This is a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in#12065904).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `apply` with `in`:

```
print (my_df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
print (my_df[my_df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1)])
          A                               B
0  [aa, ab]  [[aa, ab], [ba, bb], [bc, bd]]
2  [bc, bd]            [[aa, ab], [bc, bd]]
```