# Check if a pandas series contains a set of variables:

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, indexing, series

In a python dictionary it is very clean to make the following check:

```
import pandas as pd

myDict      = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
mySeries    = pd.Series(data = [1,2,3], index = ['a', 'b', 'c']) 

if myDict.viewkeys() >= {'a', 'b'}:
    print 'a and b are in dictionary'
```

However, I cannot find a easy way to do the same with a pandas series... Which is the pythonic way?

Comment: sorry are you after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/how-to-filter-the-dataframe-rows-of-pandas-by-within-in? if so then this is a dupe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer, but you can simply convert the series to `set` and then use the same methodology you used with the dictionary:

```
df = pd.Series(data = [1, 2, 3], index = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(set(df) >= {1, 2})
# True
```