# Retrieve row using cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
    A    B
1   1    3
2   11   4
3   2    5
4   22   6
```

I would like to retrieve the full rows when the value in A matches a value in this list:

```
list = [11, 22]
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values

Comment: `df[df['A'].isin(lst)]` will give you your desired result.

Comment: also `df.query('A in @lst')`