# How to select rows where items of two columns match with items of two lists (same index), using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, select

The question is the same as the one answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values) but extended to two conditionals. This may be tricky because the Pandas method 'isin' cannot be used as that would result in looking at combinations of items in my two lists, while what I want is to compare (and select) the dataframe items corresponding to list items of identical index (e.g. pairs of xn,yn from lists of X=[x1,x2,...xn], Y=[y1,y2,..yn]). The lists can be converted to a dataframe if needed.

Is there a way to generalize this to multiple (more than two) conditionals in Pandas?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What is it tricky? Are you looking for something like this? `df[(df['col1'].isin(list1)) & (df['col2'].isin(list2))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df[df['col1'].isin(list1) & df['col2'].isin(list2)]
```

This will return the rows of `df` where the value of `col1` exists in `list1` and the value of `col2` exists in `list2`.

`&` is the bitwise AND operator, and will return True on the indices where both the operands are True.

Comment: It's like you [read my mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915075/how-to-select-rows-where-items-of-two-columns-match-with-items-of-two-lists-sam#comment84836705_48915075).

Comment: Wasn't 100% sure my implementation would work though, so glad you could confirm :P

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. But thanks to both of you!

Comment: What's the difference between `&` and `AND`? You make it sound like they're interchangeable.

Comment: @Steve `&` _means_ `bitwise AND`, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation. It is not the same as python's `and` operator, which tries to return a single `True` or `False` (and in this case should throw an error). Put simply, `&` is the same as calling `and` on each individual pair of elements and creating a new array out of that.

Comment: @solonome I think you might have forgotten to mark the answer :)

Comment: @mxbi Actually this doesn't seem to work. I basically have two lists of latitude and longitude and a dataframe with lat and lon. The only partially overlap. I want to select the dataframe rows that match the lat,lon pair from the list. But I think this solution you suggest looks for all combinations of lat and lon from my two lists. Is this possible or is something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What worked in the end is something like this:

```
df4=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.keys())
for i, lat in enumerate(list1): 
    lon = list2[i]
    df2 = df[df["Lat"]==lat]
    df3 = df2[df2["Lon"]==lon]
    df4 = pd.concat([df4, df3],ignore_index=True)
```

Maybe not the most efficient way.