# Python Pandas Dataframe subset based on list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I am trying to create a subset in one dataframe based on the results of another dataframe (each dataframe represents a different time period and I am trying to compare period over period change based on the current top 5 teams revenue vs last period's revenue).  The top 5 analysis in the current dataframe resulted in the following categorical list:

```
results = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow']
```

I would like to feed that list into the following statement:

```
DP1 = (DPcurr.groupby(['Team'], as_index=False)
    .sum()
    .sort_values('Revenue', ascending=False)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .rename(columns={'index': 'Team_sort'})
    )
```

So that the result set from the above statement only looks at the 5 teams/colors that are listed in the list and ignores all other teams/colors

Comment: Just subset the `DataFrame` before you perform the operation, `DPcurr[DPcurr.Team.isin(results)].groupby(...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful!

Comment: No problem. Another option is to reindex after the calculation. That might be more appropriate, if for instance, `DPcurr` didn't contain a color listed in `results` but you still wanted that row in your final calculation.