# Remove Values from Pandas Dataframe Based off of Excluded Values Contained in List

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe, which looks as follows:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
A   1   Y8
B   1   G2
C   1   T1
D   2   A6
E   2   P0
F   3   M2
G   4   O2
```

I want to remove all values from this dataframe which appear in this list, called 'excl_list', if they are contained in Column3. The idea would be to exclude by the list object and not the individual items in the list:

```
['A6','P0','M2']
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values)

Comment: `df.loc[~df['Column3'].isin(['A6','P0','M2'])]` ?

Comment: Actually, this is probably a more relevant 
 duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-implement-in-and-not-in-for-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, to exclude members of the list from being in Column3:

```
df.loc[~df['Column3'].isin(excl_list)]
```

The first part, `df['Column3'].isin(excl_list)`, returns a sequence of True/False terms, one for each row in `df`.  The `~` flips all Trues and Falses, and `df.loc[]` looks up the trues.