# Simple way to select elements of a list that intersect with another list? (python)

Tags: python

In R, if I want all elements of `x` that are in `y`, I'd do

```
x[x %in% y]
```

In python, I can use list comprehension:

```
[i for i in y if i in x]
```

Is there a cleaner/more readable way?  I'm getting the hang of python, but the code that I'm writing isn't nearly as readable as I'm accustomed to.  The first thing I tried didn't work:

```
x[x in y]
```

I guess because `in` only takes scalars in python.

Comment: `in` can be used with any type of object that supports it. If you want a list that's about the cleanest way, but different data structures provide different methods

Answer (score 5):

You are correct: Python operations are not vectorised by default. In this respect, R more closely parallels the API for 3rd party [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) than regular Python. So you can use Pandas series objects:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8])

res = x[x.isin(y)]

print(res)  # output Pandas series
# 1    2
# 3    4
# dtype: int64

print(res.values)  # output NumPy array representation
# array([2, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Pandas builds on [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), so not surprisingly you can do the equivalent in NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8])

res = x[np.isin(x, y)]

print(res)
# array([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set.

```
list(set(x).intersection(y))
```

Comment: The methods such as intersection don't require the argument to be a set, so you can write `set(x).intersection(y)`. If you have two sets, you can use operators such as `set(x) & set(y)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a MyList type that will have behaviour that you want, by defining custom **getitem**() methof

```
from collections import UserList, Iterable

class MyList(UserList):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Iterable):
            return MyList(x for x in self.data if x in item)
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = MyList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    v = l[[2, 3, 11]]
    print(v)  # [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

This questions has been addressed here:
[Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values)

Here's an example using the .isin() method, equivalent to R's %in%.

```
>> x = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
>> y = pd.Series([1,3,5,6])

>> x[x.isin(y)]

0    1
2    3
4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, you can also write it as:

```
[i if i in x else None for i in y]
```

This puts the conditionals in front and the loop at the back, meaning you can do something like this:

```
[i if i in x else i/2 if i in z else i/3 for i in y]
```

Comment: In what version of python ? I can not do it in 2.7 and 3.6.2 ?

Comment: @TomaszSwider Have you tried it? Create `y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `x = [1,2,3]`, `z = [4,5]`, then run the code I've put in my answer.

Comment: You can writer the second expresion but the first is a syntax error, so you can do [x if foo else y for x in a_list] but not [x if x in something for x in a_alist].

Comment: @ Tomasz Swider  You're right. I'll edit my answer to account for that. Its weird that the first doesn't work but the second does.

Comment: No realy the second one is a ternary expresion so it evaluates to one value, and the first one is a syntax error :)