# Select rows whose column value matches a list of values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have the 1st dataframe called 'permits_df' with a column named 'FSA'.

```
> permits_df.head()
    FSA Licence No.           Category              Operating Name
0   M9N B02-4741962 PRIVATE TRANSPORTATION COMPANY  TAXIFY
1   M3J B02-4728645 PRIVATE TRANSPORTATION COMPANY  INSTARYDE
2   M6K B02-4653451 PRIVATE TRANSPORTATION COMPANY  UBER CANADA
3   M2J B02-4691773 PRIVATE TRANSPORTATION COMPANY  FACEDRIVE
4   M8Z B02-4714142 PRIVATE TRANSPORTATION COMPANY  RIDEIN
```

I have the 2nd dataframe called 'hood_df' with a column named 'list_of_fsa'

```
    CTUID     CTNAME CMAPUID PRUID HOODNUM      HOODNAME     FCOUNT list_of_fsa
0   5350218.0   218.0   35535   35  16      Stonegate-Queensway 4   M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z
1   5350217.0   217.0   35535   35  16      Stonegate-Queensway 4   M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z
2   5350216.0   216.0   35535   35  16      Stonegate-Queensway 4   M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z
3   5350215.0   215.0   35535   35  16      Stonegate-Queensway 4   M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z
4   5350219.0   219.0   35535   35  16      Stonegate-Queensway 4   M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z


type(hood_df['list_of_fsa'][0])
> str
```

For each FSA in `permits_df['FSA']`, I need to compare it with the values of all rows of FSA's in `hood_df['list_of_fsa']` . If a match in FSA occurs, I need to merge that record from `hood_df` with the record of `permits_df` where the input_FSA was matched.

The problem for me lies in the fact that I have to compare between the input_FSA in `permit_df['FSA']` and the **COLLECTION** of FSA's in `hood_df['list_of_fsa']`. It would have been easy to do an `inner join` using `df.merge()` if   `hood_df['list_of_fsa']` contained only 1 FSA inside it. But I'm not sure how to find a match between `M8Z` and `M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z` and then do a `df.merge()`. How do I go about this?

There are [similar sounding questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values) on Stack Overflow but they do not help as I need to use 2 different dataframes, and not select records from the same dataframe.

Comment: It seems you already know the key word you need to be searching for - "merge"

Comment: However what you don't seem to know is that images of data are explicitly discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and [edit] your question to include your data as _text_ that we can copy-paste.

Comment: @roganjosh: The problem for me lies in the fact that I have to compare between the input_FSA in permit_df['FSA'] and the COLLECTION of FSA's in hood_df['list_of_fsa']. It would have been easy to do an inner join using df.merge() if  hood_df['list_of_fsa'] contained only 1 FSA inside it. But I'm not sure how to find a match between M8Z and M6S,M8X,M8Y,M8Z and then do a df.merge(). How do I go about this?