# Scala : Filter DF rows based upon column value which exists in a predefined Array Spark 1.6

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

My question is almost similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values)

I have a data frame and I need to filter out the rows whose column value isn't a substring in the predefined array.

For example: List = ["apple" , "grapes" , "melon"]

```
+--------+-----------+
|quantity|      fruit|
+--------+-----------+
|      12|      apple|
|      24|green apple|
|       6|     grapes|
|      11|      mango|
|      12| watermelon|
|      15|  muskmelon|
|      22|    berries|
+--------+-----------+
```

After filtering using the array, my df should look like:

```
+--------+-----------+
|quantity|      fruit|
+--------+-----------+
|      12|      apple|
|      24|green apple|
|       6|     grapes|
|      12| watermelon|
|      15|  muskmelon|
+--------+-----------+
```

rows with column values "mango" and "berries" should be filtered out because the substrings don't exist in the predefined list.

Any suggestions or ideas in spark 1.6?

Answer (score -1):

Use **`.rlike`** function by making a string with `|` from List.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
/*
+--------+-----------+
|quantity|      fruit|
+--------+-----------+
|      12|      apple|
|      24|green apple|
|       6|     grapes|
|      11|      mango|
|      12| watermelon|
|      15|  muskmelon|
|      22|    berries|
+--------+-----------+
*/

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val list=Seq("apple" , "grapes" , "melon").mkString("|")
//list: String = apple|grapes|melon

df.filter(col("fruit").rlike(list)).show()
/*
+--------+-----------+
|quantity|      fruit|
+--------+-----------+
|      12|      apple|
|      24|green apple|
|       6|     grapes|
|      12| watermelon|
|      15|  muskmelon|
+--------+-----------+
*/
```