# Filter Pandas Dataframe based on multiple columns with multiple values per single column

Tags: python, pandas

hope some one can help me.

Given one value per column, I succeeded in filtering a Pandas Dataframe (as shown in code below). However, depending on the analysis I am running, sometimes I would like to avoid specifying a value to filter for (for example, I would like to ignore the filtering by seg_device and filter the dataframe based on the os only).

However, the code below is forcing me to always specify some value (e.g. desktop). If I leave  `seg_device` blank, `df_ch_seg` will return no data, given the condition `df_ch.device == seg_device`.

Would someone have any advice on how to make my code more flexible? My dataset is made of 1 million rows, per 16 columns. Below you see only 2 filters, but I have 15 in total (some of them are integers, some are strings columns). Thank you!

By looking at the code below, I would like to slightly change it so that it works in multiple occasions:

- if I want to filter by one device (e.g. mobile)
- if i want to filter by 2 device (e.g. mobile, desktop)
- if I don't want to filter by device (I would like my code to ignore the filter by device)

```
# [...]

seg_device = input('Enter device (e.g. desktop, ...): ')
seg_os = input('Enter operating system (e.g. Mac/iOS, Windows, ...):  ')

# [...]

# Define new dataframe df_ch_seg, based on df_ch, segmented based on above input values 
df_ch_seg = df_ch[(df_ch.device == seg_device)& (df_ch.os == seg_os)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter dataframe rows if value in column is in a set list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065885/filter-dataframe-rows-if-value-in-column-is-in-a-set-list-of-values)

Comment: Hi @Deepak, unfortunately it doesn't answer. I can give you more info with about the example. In my database, I have 3 "device" values allowed to be inserted (mobile, desktop, tablet). By looking at the code above, I would like to slightly change it so that it works in multiple occasions:
- if I want to filter by one device (e.g. mobile) 
- if i want to filter by 2 device (e.g. mobile, desktop) 
- if I don't want to filter by device (I would like my code to ignore the filter by device)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want to make this in to a function where the inputs provided will be tuples of (column, filter_value).

```
from ast import literal_eval

def mask_constructor(filters):
    mask = []
    for (col, val) in filters:
        op = (f"df_ch[{col}] == {val}")
        mask.append(op)
    return literal_eval(" & ".join(mask))
```

Then you could call it like so.

```
mask = mask_constructor(("device", "iPhone"), ("os", "iOS"))
df_ch[mask]
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this does not solve the problem yet. It allows me to filter by 2 values using the list, but not to ignore the filtering. I edited the final part of my problem to provide more info with an example. Thank you again

Comment: yes but in this function you pass in the columns and filters you want. If you don’t want to use a specific column then don’t pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code can help. Here 'a' is seg_device and 'b' is seg_os. So make sure that a='' and b=''. If you don't specify (input) 'a' then 'a' will be set to df['A'] and thereby all values in that column will be valid. The same could be done for 'b' and other columns in your Data Frame. Hope this is clear.

```
d = {'A':['a','b','a','b','a'], 'B':[1,2,3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

a ='' # a is not specified and remains empty
if a=='': 
  a=df['A'] # set 'a' to all values in df['A'] 
b=1

(df['A']==a) & (df['B']>b)
```