# Taking subset of rows from a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, dataset

'hypothesis' is a column in the crop_dataset which is itself of type

```
<class `'datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset'>



searchfor = ['she', 'he','his','her','him','boys','woman','Woman','girl','men','man','female','girls']
```

dataframe approach

```
df_temp = datasets.Dataset.to_pandas(crop_dataset)

rows_where_found = df_temp.filter(lambda example: searchfor in example['hypothesis'])

returns empty
```

How do I choose the rows where any of these words appear and create a subset

example of data:

```
print(crop_dataset['hypothesis'][0:3])

['A person is training his horse for a competition.', 'A person is at a diner, ordering an omelette.', 'A person is outdoors, on a horse.']
```

Comment: You want check one of ```searchfor``` elements into one of ```crop_dataset``` list of dictionary? I.e. crop_dataset has format ```[{'hypothesis': string or list?, 'shape': data}, ...]```?

Comment: {'premise': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'hypothesis': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=3, names=['entailment', 'neutral', 'contradiction'], names_file=None, id=None)}

This is the the structure of crop_datset

Comment: crop_dataset is list of those structures?

Comment: yes. it is collectively called

datasets.arrow_dataset.Dataset

Comment: I think that you logic is ```rows_where_found = crop_dataset.filter(lambda example: example['hypothesis'] in searchfor)``` if type of ```crop_dataset``` has method ```filter```

Comment: I changed my searchfor to searchfor = [r'\bshe\b', r'\bhe\b',r'\bhis\b',r'\bher\b',r'\bhim\b',r'\bboys\b',r'\bwoman\b',r'\bWoman\b',r'\bgirl\b',r'\bmen\b',r'\bman\b',r'\bfemale\b',r'\bgirls\b']

thinking regex makes more sense. And tried your fix, returns empty

Comment: Without change correct result by strings without regexp?

Comment: Actually example['hypothesis'] is a much longer sentence so we can't look for it in the list of search strings

No, same result

Comment: I can try using dataframes but it is buggy. I'll update my ques

Comment: ```import re``` and string for resulting ```rows_where_found = crop_dataset.filter(lambda example: any(re.match(r, example) for r in searchfor))```

Comment: without re and with string list ```rows_where_found = crop_dataset.filter(lambda example: any(r in example for r in searchfor))```

Comment: the regex version crashes and the list version returns empty

Comment: any(r in example for r in searchlist)) <-- how does this part return the whole sentence? I think it does not

Comment: write example of your data and result that you want to get

Comment: please see the update above

Comment: ```rows_where_found = [hypo for hypo in crop_dataset['hypothesis'] if any(word in hypo for word in searchfor)]``` with filter and lambda ```rows_where_found = list(filter(lambda hypo: any(word in hypo for word in searchfor), crop_dataset['hypothesis']))

Comment: still both result in empty. Could you check the dataframe approach, I think that might be better to adapt?

Comment: may be that ```rows_where_found = df_temp.filter(lambda example: any(word in example['hypothesis'] for word in searchfor))```

Comment: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: the goal is to save the whole row btw not the word

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26724725/3928155

Comment: isin() would look for exact match between the whole sentence and the list of words I am looking for. Which might be issue

Comment: new = df_temp['hypothesis'].isin(searchlist)
creates a long list of boolean 1 and 0s